# How to find the line containing most words from a wordlist between randomly generated strings

Tags: text-processing

I want to get the line containing most words from a wordlist in my `ls` output.

In my case its onion v3 addresses as directories and I want to get the most readable one.

Example line:

```
vww6ybal4bd7szmgncyruucpgfkqahzddi37ktceo3ah7ngmcopnpyyd.onion
```

Comment: So what would the result be for your example? `bal`, `cop`, and `ion` would be the words from that string, apart from `onion`, if you filter the dictionary for words of three or more characters.

Comment: And your most English word in that case would be? "ah" or "cop"? The only vowels present are a, u, i, e, and o, and u does not repeat. The letter frequency of random text is nothing like that of actual language, so words of 4 or more letters will be very rare. I assume every name is .onion as a file extension.

Comment: I would use a customized wordlist with words that have a length of 5 or more characters. I edited the question to make that clear, an answer helping me would a command chain or something alike to achieve that. Also as i have generated roughly 15 million onion addresses, where a lot contain more than 5 characters, now i just need to get the one that contains the most.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
$ s=vww6ybal4bd7szmgncyruucpgfkqahzddi37ktceo3ah7ngmcopnpyyd.onion
$ min=3 max=16
$ a=(); for ((i=1;i<=l-min+1;i++)) for ((j=i+min-1;j<=l&&j-i+1<=max;j++)) a+=$s[i,j]
$ b=($(grep -xE "[[:lower:]]{$min,$max}" /usr/share/dict/words))
$ print ${a:*b}
ceo cop oni onion ion
$ print ${#a:*b}
5
```